# Can we pull posts out of Stack Overflow based on tags?

Tags: support, questions, search

Instead of directly searching the posts and reading on the Stack Overflow website, can we pull out posts in the form of pdf/txt file?

I want to learn (say like programming: c or python) some real life workarounds/problems faced by users beyond what's in the book.

Is there any valid way to get the information from [stackoverflow.com/search?q=](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any valid way to get the information from stackoverflow.com/search?q=?

Use [the `/search/advanced` route of the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search); that's what it's there for.

For example:
    [/2.2/search/advanced?q=foo&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&q=foo&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow&filter=!6xGkKBjMFEsggJ0Seh_gbZnVfTGRRZ8p4J0H.I5eWQpMouFLr_cY9879QQs8b49fw1dnI)
    <sub><sup>([Doc page equivalent](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=foo&tagged=python&filter=!6xGkKBjMFEsggJ0Seh_gbZnVfTGRRZ8p4J0H.I5eWQpMouFLr_cY9879QQs8b49fw1dnI&site=stackoverflow&run=true))</sup></sub>